# with vimgrep - or other vim possibility - how can i get groups of data out of a file?

Tags: vim, vimgrep

I'm trying to do a vimgrep on a file in order to get only two attributs with their values out of the xml file.
so far i can get the complete lines  and i'd like with the help of groups to have a better display.

:vimgrep key= % | copen

^ I'd like to add to this command the grouping possibility with "(  )" ....but without success for the moment.

i'd appreciate your help in order to have a result as explained in the "result  expected"

part of the file that I'm working with :

```html
 
<policy name="Menu_Controls" class="User" displayName="$(string.Menu_Controls)" explainText="$(string.IE_ExplainMenu_Controls)" presentation="$(presentation.Menu_Controls)" key="Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AllowedControls">
      <parentCategory ref="AdminApproved" />
      <supportedOn ref="SUPPORTED_IE5" />
      <elements>
        <boolean id="MCSiMenu" valueName="{275E2FE0-7486-11D0-89D6-00A0C90C9B67}">
          <trueValue>
            <decimal value="0" />
          </trueValue>
          <falseValue>
            <decimal value="1" />
          </falseValue>
        </boolean>
        <boolean id="PopupMenu_Object" valueName="{7823A620-9DD9-11CF-A662-00AA00C066D2}">
          <trueValue>
            <decimal value="0" />
          </trueValue>
          <falseValue>
            <decimal value="1" />
          </falseValue>
        </boolean>
        <boolean id="Ikonic_Control" valueName="{F5131C24-E56D-11CF-B78A-444553540000}">
          <trueValue>
            <decimal value="0" />
          </trueValue>
          <falseValue>
            <decimal value="1" />
          </falseValue>
        </boolean>
      </elements>
    </policy>
    <policy name="Microsoft_Agent" class="User" displayName="$(string.Microsoft_Agent)" explainText="$(string.IE_Explain_Microsoft_Agent)" presentation="$(presentation.Microsoft_Agent)" key="Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AllowedControls">
      <parentCategory ref="AdminApproved" />
      <supportedOn ref="SUPPORTED_IE5" />
      <elements>
        <boolean id="Microsoft_Agent_Control" valueName="{D45FD31B-5C6E-11D1-9EC1-00C04FD7081F}">
          <trueValue>
            <decimal value="0" />
          </trueValue>
          <falseValue>
            <decimal value="1" />
          </falseValue>
        </boolean>
      </elements>
    </policy>
```

my expected result :

```html
 name="Menu_Controls"  key="Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AllowedControls"
 name="Microsoft_Agent" key="Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AllowedControls"
```

thanks in advance for your help. 
toshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two cmds could do it:

```
v/<policy /d
```

then

```
%s/.* \(name="[^"]*"\).*\(key="[^"]*"\).*/\1 \2/g
```

Comment: Hello, your first line highlight policy in all my file. 
Can you explain this first line please. 

I understand :
v -> visual , 
/<policy -> search for <policy, 
but what about /d ?

Comment: @toshi oh, sorry, my bad, it is not `v` visual, I meant "command :v". so it should be `:v/<......./d`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.....that why all my not desired lines were still on file ;) Anyway, your answer is exactly what i was looking for, the substitute with groups.

Answer (score 0):

My [ExtractMatches plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4795) provides a `:YankMatches` command, with which you can extract the matches and put them into a scratch buffer. As a one-liner:

```
:execute 'YankMatches \<\%(name\|key\)="[^"]*"' | new | put!
```

Result:

```
name="Menu_Controls"
key="Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AllowedControls"
name="Microsoft_Agent"
key="Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AllowedControls"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find `:vimgrep` and the quickfix list really helpful, you can use the [editqf.vim plugin](https://github.com/jceb/vim-editqf) to make the quickfix list of your grep results editable, and then use e.g. a variation of the `:%s` command given in @Kent's answer to strip off the extraneous stuff.